# Launch the same program with different arguments in parallel via bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have a program that has very big computation times. I need to call it with different arguments. I want to run them on a server with a lot of processors, so I'd like to launch them in parallel in order to save time. (One program instance only uses one processor)

I have tried my best to write a bash script which looks like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

# set maximal number of parallel jobs
MAXPAR=5
#  fill the PID array with nonsense pid numbers
for (( PAR=1; PAR<=MAXPAR; PAR++ ))
do
   PID[$PAR]=-18
done


# loop over the arguments
for ARG in 50 60 70 90
do
   # endless loop that checks, if one of the parallel jobs has finished
   while true
   do
      # check if PID[PAR] is still running, suppress error output of kill
      if ! kill -0 ${PID[PAR]} 2> /dev/null
      then
         # if PID[PAR] is not running, the next job
         # can run as parellel job number PAR
         break
      fi

      # if it is still running, check the next parallel job
      if [ $PAR -eq $MAXPAR ]
      then
         PAR=1
      else
         PAR=$[$PAR+1]
      fi

      # but sleep 10 seconds before going on
      sleep 10
   done

   # call to the actual program (here sleep for example)
   #./complicated_program $ARG &
   sleep $ARG &

   # get the pid of the process we just started and save it as PID[PAR]
   PID[$PAR]=$!

   # give some output, so we know where we are
   echo ARG=$ARG, par=$PAR, pid=${PID[PAR]}
done
```

Now, this script works, but I don't quite like it.

- Is there any better way to deal with the beginning? (Setting `PID[*]=-18` looks wrong to me)
- How do I wait for the first job to finish without the ugly infinite loop and sleeping some seconds? I know there is `wait`, but I'm not sure how to use it here.
- I'd be grateful for any comments on how to improve style and conciseness.

Comment: Consider using `parallel` or `xargs -P` instead of reinventing them

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity, I'm with @thatotherguy, and he refers to GNU Parallel at https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/

Comment: Your command will then look like `parallel do something ::: 50 60 70 90`

Comment: I'm (thanks to @thatotherguy) aware of GNU Parallel and how to use it. I consider using it. On the other hand I see that GNU Parallel can do a lot more and I'd like to keep it simple and stupid.

Comment: I would really recommend against keeping it stupid, and just keeping it simple instead. If you can write a simple for loop that can run your commands in serial, you can just prefix the commands with `sem -j 5` (an alias for `parallel --semaphore`) and it should basically just work.

Comment: `sem` seems to be doing exactly what I want. I wasn't aware that `parallel` had this option. This does keep it very simple!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the tips @theotherguy gave in the comments, I rewrote the script in a better way using the `sem` command that comes with GNU Parallel:

```
#!/bin/bash

# set maximal number of parallel jobs
MAXPAR=5

# loop over the arguments
for ARG in 50 60 70 90
do
   # call to the actual program (here sleep for example)
   # prefixed by sem -j $MAXPAR
   #sem -j $MAXPAR   ./complicated_program $ARG
   sem -j $MAXPAR   sleep $ARG

   # give some output, so we know where we are
   echo ARG=$ARG
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a much more complicated code that, more or less, does the same thing.
The things you need to consider:

- Does the user need to approve the spawning of a new thread
- Does the user need to approve the killing of an old thread
- Does the thread terminate on it's own or it needs to be killed
- Does the user want the script to run endlessly, as long as it has MAXPAR threads
- If so, does the user need an escape sequence to stop further spawning

Here is some code for you:

```
    spawn()                              #function that spawns a thread
    {                                    #usage: spawn 1 ls -l
        i=$1                             #save the thread index
        shift 1                          #shift arguments to the left
        [ ${thread[$i]} -ne 0 ] &&       #if the thread is not already running
        [ ${#thread[@]} -lt $threads] && #and if we didn't reach maximum number of threads,
        $@ &                             #run the thread in the background, with all the arguments
        thread[$1]=$!                    #associate thread id with thread index
    }

    terminate()                          #function that terminates threads
    {                                    #usage: terminate 1
        [ your condition ] &&            #if your condition is met,
        kill {thread[$1]} &&             #kill the thread and if so,
        thread[$1]=0                     #mark the thread as terminated
    }
```

Now, the rest of the code depends on your needs (things to consider), so you will either loop through input arguments and call spawn, and then after some time loop through threads indexes and call terminate. Or, if the threads end on their own, loop through input arguments and call both spawn and terminate,but the condition for the terminate is then:

```
[ ps -aux 2>/dev/null | grep " ${thread[$i]} " &>/dev/null ]
#look for thread id in process list (note spaces around id)
```

Or, something along the lines of that, you get the point.

Comment: So you are more or less using `0` instead of `-18` to mark a free thread slot. I think I understand how to use `spawn` and `terminate`, but wouldn't I have to use some kind of infinite `sleep`y loop to see when a process has ended?
Is using `ps -aux | grep " $pid "` really preferrable to `kill -0 $pid`?

Comment: I wasn't aware of `-0`, so yes, it does not rely on `ps` layout and does not require `grep`. Smart. To mark the slot empty, use any value that is not going to collide with a process id, that is, anything that is not a positive integer (`null` or `foo` would work as well)